# Handling multi user scenarios in python bottle with an os.system command

Tags: python, bottle, os.system

I am using python bottle server for my rest api.On getting the request i am using an os.system to call an RScript. The rscript takes some time to execute after which it continues the operation.My problem is when multiple users are using the api,it is getting queued and not happening parallel.

```
@route('/UploadFiles', method='POST')
def UploadFiles():

    #Reading the initial text file to get application name and other details
    with open('/home/user/abc.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            if('Application Name' in line):
                appName=line.split(" - ")
                appName=str(appName[1])
                appName=appName.strip()


    print "inside upload files"
    uniquename=str(uuid.uuid1())
    print "uuid is :",uniquename



    retcode = subprocess.call(['Rscript','/home/user/RProgram.r',uniquename])
    print "executed r script"


run(host='192.168.1.155', port=8555)
```

All these has to happen parallely for every user. But it is getting queued. What am i doing wrong here.

I am running using

```
sudo nohup python restcall.py -&
```

so the print statements are not the issue i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a solution. It is working now for me.Bottle runs on the built-in wsgiref WSGIServer by default. This non-threading HTTP server is perfectly fine for development and early production, but may become a performance bottleneck when server load increases.

The easiest way to increase performance is to install a multi-threaded server library like paste or cherrypy and tell Bottle to use that instead of the single-threaded server:

```
bottle.run(server='paste')
```

[Referencing python bottle documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html)

Comment: why not use cherrypy as the http server?